# iOS app crashes - [NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, compiler-errors

i am an amateur ios developer with version 4.6 of xcode and OSX 10.8.4. I am trying to make an app which plays sound but when i try to run the app i get this message:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -                       [NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

My app also wont launch.

Here is the code for my view controller.h:

```
      ViewController.h:

 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController 



- (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)stopButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

And here is my view controller.m:

```
      Viewcontroller.m:


#import "ViewController.h"
#import <RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h>


@interface ViewController ()
{
AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController 
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
NSString *stringPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"98648__dobroide__20100606-mosquito" ofType:@"mp3"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath];

NSError *error;

avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

[avPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

 }


- (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender {
[avPlayer play];
}

- (IBAction)stopButton:(id)sender {
[avPlayer pause];

}
@end
```

Comment: Are you sure that 98648__dobroide__20100606-mosquito.mp3 exists in your bundle? Case sensitivity matters.

Comment: i copied and pasted it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is `pathForResource` is returning nil. Have you added that exact file name to your bundle?

Also, you should be testing for `stringPath` and `error` before continuing to load the player. For example:

```
NSString *stringPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"98648__dobroide__20100606-mosquito" ofType:@"mp3"];
if (stringPath) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath];
    NSError *error;
    avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    if (!error) {
        [avPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error occurred: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"Resource not found");
}
```

Comment: Fair question, +1 to balance out the -1